What does "Not that half" mean?
In Oppenheimer (2023), Frank is going to marry waitress Jackie:

Frank: We join the Party and you can't hide your disapproval. Why? Is
that because that's supposed to be your thing?
Robert: I haven't joined the Party, Frank. And I don't think she
should have convinced you to either.
Frank: Half of the faculty is Communist.
Robert: Not that half.

What does "Not that half" mean ?

Presumably he means The half of the faculty that's my thing isn't that half (the Communist half). Logically, it's a bit mixed up, but it's just conversation. Google tells me The tragic suffering inflicted by Joseph Stalin on Russian scientists led him [Oppenheimer] to withdraw his associations with the Communist Party—in fact, he never joined the party.

Presumably he means the half of the faculty that matters, is important to his success, has power and connections, could make trouble for him if they found out he had Communist connections. Without more context, we Dan’s be certain.

Is it possibly referring to something earlier in the conversation?

Better asked on Movies and TV SE. It's asking for an explanation of a reference in a film, not for the meaning of words. (Although the OP should really explain that they know what "not that half" means generally, or that they tried to find out.)

I just read the transcript of that sequence of the film and the meaning of the phrase (in context) is a mystery to me.   Unless it means "I'm not in that half."   Like when someone says "I don't see why you dislike X. Most people love it.  -- Not most people" and the elliptical retort "Not most people" means "I'm not most people".
